# Remap Capslock to Esc and disable original Esc key in AutoHotkey

Tags: autohotkey

Remapping <kbd>Capslock</kbd> to <kbd>Esc</kbd> like so works:

```
Capslock::Esc
```

But when I add the following remappings (<kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Alt-Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-Esc</kbd>):

```
Esc::
!Esc::
^Esc::
return
```

... for disabling the original <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, the Capslock remapping no longer works.

How can I remap <kbd>Capslock</kbd> to <kbd>Esc</kbd> and disable the original <kbd>Esc</kbd> key completely?

I hope you can help me, please.

Comment: I dont have the answer to your question. But if you disable `Esc` and then remap `Capslock` to `Esc` then you are remaping `Capslock` to disabled key. Thants why `Capslock` does not works, because it is maped to disabled key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @vasili told, your <kbd>Capslock</kbd> goes to <kbd>Esc</kbd>, which is disabled.

From example in [documentaition](http://ahkscript.org/docs/misc/Remap.htm), I have found that, if you want to switch two keys you should write something like this:

```
a::b
b::a
```

So using this logic I tried to put some usually not used key:

```
Capslock::Esc

Esc::F15
^!Esc::F15
!Esc::F15
^Esc::F15
```

<kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>F24</kbd> - The 12 or more function keys at the top of most keyboards.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an easier one using wildcard (*) and without mapping to unused key:

```
Capslock::Esc ; Remap Capslock to Esc
*Esc::return  ; Disable Esc pressed with zero or any combination of modifiers
```

If it doesn't work, add a $ to block the trigger loop:

```
Capslock::Esc ; Remap Capslock to Esc
$*Esc::return ; Disable Esc pressed with zero or any combination of modifiers
```

To disable just certain combinations of Esc:

```
Capslock::Esc
$Esc::
$!Esc::
$^Esc::
return
```